# postman - post application/json data

Tags: json, node.js, express, postman

How can I send application/json data through postman, so that i can recieve the same data in nodejs server as req.body.
I have tried raw body json in postman which sends the data as application/json, but data is available in server as req.rawBody. I need to get the same in req.body. Is there any such option

Comment: Have you set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json?`

Comment: Also be sure to use body-parser

Comment: yes i tried both. but no result

Comment: Please see the below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41955103/cant-get-post-data-using-nodejs-expressjs-and-postman/53514520#53514520 It will help you

Answer (score 3):

Click on x-www-form-urlencoded tab and enter the body. Now you can receive the body using `req.body` in backend.

Comment: but here the data is send as x-www-form-urlencoded form. I need the data to be send as application/json

Answer (score 2):

First, you must choose an http method that supports a body like "POST", "PUT", or "PATCH".  Because "GET" and "DELETE" don't support a body.

Then you choose a data type of "raw" and paste/type your JSON data.

[image: Screenshot of the amazing POSTman!]

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem. Did u try this in your main .js file?

```
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
     extended: true
  }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use following syntax in server file

> `const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
>   const cors = require('cors');  app.use(cors()) // for crossOrigin Access
>
>   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false})) 
>   app.use(bodyParser.json())`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send files with a json you can use the multiform-data in postman. 
use multer npm extension to get the files and use JSON.parse(request.body) to pars the json and access its fields.